# determine the coefficient of $x^2yz$ in the expansion of $(2x-y+z+1)^7$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

> determine the coefficient of $x^2yz$ in the expansion of $(2x-y+z+1)^7$

I found this question in my textbook , i seem very easy in the beginning but my answer is wrong according to answerkey.

I said that the coefficient is equal to $\frac{7!}{2! \times 1 \times 1 \times 3!} \times 2^2 \times (-1)$

However ,the answer is $-280$. What am i missing ?

Comment: Actually I think he did account for it with the $3!$ in the denominator. Sure he could multiply by $1^3$ but that won't change the answer.

Comment: I have checked it a few times and it looks like you are right and your answer key is wrong.  Maybe I'm making the same mistake you are but what you did looks right.

Comment: The answer is not -280, look that https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=coefficient+of+x%5E2yz+in+%282x+-+y+%2B+z+%2B+1%29%5E7.
Your answer is correct.

Comment: @MatheusVinicius thank you very much

Comment: @RobertTheTutor thank you very much

Comment: Your answer is correct, as can be seen from first principles in an expanded version of your work. To get an $x^2yz$ term from the product of $7$ copies of $2x-y+z+1$, one must choose $2x$ twice, $-y$ once, $z$ once, and $1$ three times. There are $\binom72$ ways to choose $2x$ twice, $5$ ways to choose $-y$ once from the remaining $5$ factors, then $4$ ways to choose $z$ once, at which point the other $3$ choices must all be $1$, so there are $\binom72\cdot5\cdot4=420$ $x^2yz$ terms, each of which has a coefficient of $2^2(-1)1^3=-4$, so the coefficient of $x^2yz$ is $-4\cdot420=-1680$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small crosscheck. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[x^k](ax+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}a^kz^{n-k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain by successively applying (1)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^2yz]}&\color{blue}{(2x-y+z+1)^7}\\
> &=[yz]\binom{7}{2}2^2(-y+z+1)^5\\
> &=[z]\binom{7}{2}2^2\binom{5}{1}(-1)(z+1)^4\\
> &=\binom{7}{2}2^2\binom{5}{1}(-1)\binom{4}{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-1\,680}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with OPs result.

Answer (score 0):

Just for confirmation:

$$128x^7+448x^6+672x^5+560x^4+280x^3y^4-1120x^3y^3+280x^3z^4+1120x^3z^3+280x^3-84x^2y^5+420x^2y^4-840x^2y^3+840x^2y^2z^3+2520x^2y^2z^2+840x^2y^2+84x^2z^5+420x^2z^4+840x^2z^3-840x^2z^2y^3+840x^2z^2+84x^2+14xy^6-84xy^5+210xy^4-280xy^3z^3-280xy^3+210xy^2z^4+840xy^2z^3+1260xy^2z^2+210xy^2-84xyz^5-420xyz^4-840xyz^3-840xyz^2-420xyz-84xy+14xz^6+84xz^5+210xz^4+280xz^3+210xz^2y^4-840xz^2y^3+210xz^2-84xzy^5+420xzy^4-840xzy^3+840xzy^2+84xz+14x-y^7+7y^6-21y^5+35y^4-560y^3x^4-35y^3z^4-140y^3z^3-35y^3+672y^2x^5+1680y^2x^4+1680y^2x^3+21y^2z^5+105y^2z^4+210y^2z^3+1680y^2z^2x^3+210y^2z^2+21y^2-448yx^6-1344yx^5-1680yx^4-1120yx^3z^3-1120yx^3-420yx^2z^4-1680yx^2z^3-2520yx^2z^2-420yx^2-7yz^6-42yz^5-105yz^4-140yz^3-1680yz^2x^4-3360yz^2x^3-105yz^2-1344yzx^5-3360yzx^4-3360yzx^3\color{green}{-1680yzx^2}-42yz-7y+z^7+7z^6+21z^5+35z^4+560z^3x^4+35z^3y^4+35z^3+672z^2x^5+1680z^2x^4+1680z^2x^3-21z^2y^5+105z^2y^4-210z^2y^3+21z^2+448zx^6+1344zx^5+1680zx^4-1120zx^3y^3+1120zx^3+420zx^2y^4-1680zx^2y^3+2520zx^2y^2+420zx^2+7zy^6-42zy^5+105zy^4-140zy^3+1680zy^2x^4+3360zy^2x^3+105zy^2+7z+1$$